# Executing multiple Cypher MATCH statements using SET

Tags: neo4j

Please let me know that how can i execute multiple Cypher MATCH statements using SET, for your reference I am sharing my Cypher statement with you.

```
Match (XYZ_Security:MODEL { NodeID: 'd0401381-c1db-41e9-bf08-da686242b988' }) SET XYZ_Security.Name = 'XYZ_Security', XYZ_Security.IsLookup = 'False'
Match (CUSIP:FIELD { NodeID: 'b6210beb-8fa1-44dc-bd5d-53404dbbed83' }) SET CUSIP.Name = 'CUSIP', CUSIP.IsKeyMember = 'False', CUSIP.IsValueMember = 'False', CUSIP.DataType = 'string', CUSIP.LookupItem = '', CUSIP.ValidationExpressionText = 'CUSIP != null', CUSIP.ValidationExpressionValue = 'true'

Match (Sedol:FIELD { NodeID: 'cd5c972d-7ae9-4e03-ad52-20375261f8ef' }) SET Sedol.Name = 'Sedol', Sedol.IsKeyMember = 'False', Sedol.IsValueMember = 'False', Sedol.DataType = 'string', Sedol.LookupItem = '', Sedol.ValidationExpressionText = 'Sedol != null', Sedol.ValidationExpressionValue = 'true'
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Shafeeque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write operations (like `SET`) cannot be followed by read operations (like `MATCH`) unless you separate them with a `WITH` clause. So, this would work (notice how the `WITH` clauses pass a value that is ignored, since there are no values that need to be passed):

```
MATCH (XYZ_Security:MODEL { NodeID: 'd0401381-c1db-41e9-bf08-da686242b988' })
SET
  XYZ_Security.Name = 'XYZ_Security',
  XYZ_Security.IsLookup = 'False'
WITH 1 AS ignored
MATCH (CUSIP:FIELD { NodeID: 'b6210beb-8fa1-44dc-bd5d-53404dbbed83' })
SET
  CUSIP.Name = 'CUSIP',
  CUSIP.IsKeyMember = 'False',
  CUSIP.IsValueMember = 'False',
  CUSIP.DataType = 'string',
  CUSIP.LookupItem = '',
  CUSIP.ValidationExpressionText = 'CUSIP != null',
  CUSIP.ValidationExpressionValue = 'true'
WITH 1 AS ignored
MATCH (Sedol:FIELD { NodeID: 'cd5c972d-7ae9-4e03-ad52-20375261f8ef' })
SET
  Sedol.Name = 'Sedol',
  Sedol.IsKeyMember = 'False',
  Sedol.IsValueMember = 'False',
  Sedol.DataType = 'string',
  Sedol.LookupItem = '',
  Sedol.ValidationExpressionText = 'Sedol != null',
  Sedol.ValidationExpressionValue = 'true'
```

Alternatively, you can put all the `MATCH` clauses first, followed by all the `SET` clauses.